# Getting JSON async from API in GridView

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, asynchronous, gridview

**I'm having a hard time loading a grid with async data.**

I'm getting this crash/error, I'm assuming because I don't have the data yet or something? But I'm not totally sure:

[image]

I'm pulling in JSON from `http://ramsey.api.com/hello` is as simple as:

```
[{
    "middleName": "Sarco",
    "firstName": "Marco",
    "city": "Neverland",
    "lastName": "Ramsey"
}, {
    "middleName": "Jarco",
    "firstName": "Taco",
    "city": "Niagra",
    "lastName": "Ramsey"
}]
```

Everything is pulling in just fine, and I'm also mapping it just fine to its model class:

```
public class Ramsey
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string middleName { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to pull in the data and map it to its grid bindings, I get the error.  Here is the method I'm using:

```
    public static async Task<List<Ramsey>> GetListAsyncModelPeopleManager()
    {
        var ramsey = new List<Ramsey>();

        var api = "http://ramsey.api.com/hello";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(api);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        IEnumerable<Ramsey> results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Ramsey>>(result);

        foreach (Ramsey r in results)
        {

            var first = r.firstName;
            var middle = r.middleName;
            var last = r.lastName;
            var city = r.city;

            var item = new Ramsey();
            item.firstName = first;
            item.middleName = middle;
            item.lastName = last;
            item.city = city;

            ramsey.Add(item);
        }

        return ramsey;
    }


}
```

I know my bindings are find for the grid because I can run hardcoded data with this and it's fine:

```
    public static List<Ramsey> GetListSyncModelPeopleManager()
    {
        var ramsey = new List<Ramsey>();
        ramsey.Add(new Ramsey { firstName = "Marco", city = "No City", lastName = "Ramsey" });
        ramsey.Add(new Ramsey { firstName = "Karpo", city = "Niagra", lastName = "Cropo" });
        ramsey.Add(new Ramsey { firstName = "Sarco", city = "Nacity", lastName = "Ramsey" });

        return ramsey;
    }
```

I'm newer to this so I'm still trying to figure everything out even though I've been checking out docs like [Stephen Cleary's](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [MSDN's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx).

**EDIT**

Per request here is the exception:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl.put_ItemsSource(Object value)
   at qlckitWindows.MainPage.XamlBindingSetters.Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsSource(ItemsControl obj, Object value, String targetNullValue) in \\Mac\code_repository\KIT\kitWindows\kitWindows\obj\x86\Debug\MainPage.g.cs:line 26
   at qlckitWindows.MainPage.MainPage_obj1_Bindings.Update_list3(Task`1 obj, Int32 phase) in \\Mac\code_repository\QLC\qlckitWindows\qlckitWindows\obj\x86\Debug\MainPage.g.cs:line 248
   at qlckitWindows.MainPage.MainPage_obj1_Bindings.Update_(MainPage obj, Int32 phase) in \\Mac\code_repository\QLC\qlckitWindows\qlckitWindows\obj\x86\Debug\MainPage.g.cs:line 240
   at qlckitWindows.MainPage.MainPage_obj1_Bindings.Update() in \\Mac\code_repository\QLC\qlckitWindows\qlckitWindows\obj\x86\Debug\MainPage.g.cs:line 213
   at qlckitWindows.MainPage.MainPage_obj1_Bindings.Initialize() in \\Mac\code_repository\QLC\qlckitWindows\qlckitWindows\obj\x86\Debug\MainPage.g.cs:line 207
   at qlckitWindows.MainPage.MainPage_obj1_Bindings.Loading(FrameworkElement src, Object data) in \\Mac\code_repository\QLC\qlckitWindows\qlckitWindows\obj\x86\Debug\MainPage.g.cs:line 230
```

And here is how I bind the ItemsSource of my DataGrid:

```
   <GridView x:Name="RamseyGridView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind list4}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick">  
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>  
               <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Ramsey">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="RamseyStackPan" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="RamseyStackPanel" Margin="20,20,0,0" Background="LightGray" >
                        <TextBlock x:Name="RamseyFirstName" FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind firstName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="RamseyLastName" FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind lastName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>  
                </StackPanel>  
            </DataTemplate>  
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>  
    </GridView>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for the question/response! I get a crash, and it's in the screenshot I put in my question, so what happens is I get the crash which opens up a "MainPage.g.cs" file where it shows the error "Value does not fall within the expected range".  Any ideas?  Let me know if you have any other Q's. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you try to open the design view? Can you also post the call stack you have when you get the exception?

Comment: To answer this fully we need to see how you bind the result of GetListAsyncModelPeopleManager() to the ItemsSource of your DataGrid. Can you show us the code where you do that? My first guess is that the DataGrid doesn't know how to handle Task objects.

Comment: @NicoRiff sorry I forgot to @ you earlier. "Thanks for the question/response! I get a crash, and it's in the screenshot I put in my question, so what happens is I get the crash which opens up a "MainPage.g.cs" file where it shows the error "Value does not fall within the expected range". Any ideas? Let me know if you have any other Q's. Thanks!"

Comment: @dbc I did Copy Details and edited the question to share the full details, let me know if I missed anything.  Did that make things clearer? Thanks!

Comment: @ashbygeek I added this info as an edit to the question, I hope it makes it clearer now than it was before, so thanks for suggesting to add this information.  Was it helpful in terms of something standing out why the DataGrid doesn't know how to handle the Tasks? Thanks!

Comment: @Chadley08 I added some helpful details in my question by editing that, is that the sort of thing you were looking for? Let me know if not and I can add any extra needed info for sure.  Thanks!

Comment: @SRMR That's a bundle closer, but I could also use with seeing how you specified list4, as in `{x:Bind list4}` I think my answer below is right anyhow, but you've got me curious.

Comment: @ashbygeek I specified `list4` in my `MainPage.xaml.cs` with `private List<Ramsey> list4;`, is that what you were looking for? I'm going to take a look at your answer now

Comment: @SRMR Getting pretty warm. Where and how is list4 set? Do you set it to null anywhere? Do you set it in a constructor?

Comment: @ashbygeek Ah, in `MainPage.xaml.cs`'s `public MainPage()` after `this.InitializeComponent();` I set it before with `list4 = Ramsey.GetListAsyncModelPeopleManager();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your method with the hard-coded values isn't returning quite the same thing as the actual method. Your first code sample returns `Task<List<Ramsey>>`, the hard coded one returns just a plain `List<Ramsey>`.

Here's a code sample I made to prove the point to myself.

My data class:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}
```

Functions:

```
public static async Task<List<DataModel>> GetListAsync()
{
   await Task.Delay(500);

   var list = new List<DataModel>
   {
        new DataModel() { Name = "me", City = "Atlantis" },
        new DataModel() { Name = "you", City = "Timbuktu" }
   };
   return list;
}

public static List<DataModel> GetList()
{
    var list = new List<DataModel>
    {
        new DataModel() { Name = "me", City = "Atlantis" },
        new DataModel(0 { Name = "you, City = "Timbuktu" }
    }
    return list;
}
```

So, with these function in mind and a MainWindow class that has a DataGrid in xaml named dataGrid:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://sxhemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://xchemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://sxhemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then the following constructor works just fine and you get a data grid with data in it:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   dataGrid.ItemsSource = GetList();
}
```

The following constructor won't even compile because of the Task returned:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGrid.ItemsSource = GetListAsync();
}
```

The following constructor compiles but causes the program to hang indefinitely:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var data = GetListAsync();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = data.Result;
}
```

And here's a constructor that actually works:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LoadData();

    //placing a function within a method is available in C#7 (Visual Studio 2017)
    //if you're using an older editor or C# version, just make this a private method of the MainWindow class
    async void LoadData()
    {
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = await GetListAsync();
    }
}
```

So, I don't know how you're binding your DataGrid's ItemsSource property, but it looks like you're probably doing that in XAML and then the XAML's binding methods are choking on that Task. If you change that to some sort of initialization with an Async Void method like I demonstrated in that last constructor then it should work.

Comment: Great!  So I think this is starting to make sense where the small spots in my logic are missing!  As I look thru your answer, my data class looks good so far...

Comment: When I get to Functions, I'm wondering if you're showing both methods, but actually just saying by the end to only use the `GetListAsync` method? And inside that method, it looks like you're hardcoding the data model items instead of pulling them from the API like I was?

Comment: Then for the xaml, you have <Grid> and then <DataGrid> named inside of it, where I have <GridView> and then <DataTemplate> inside of it... should I do it how you did it, or use mine but slightly edited?

Comment: (You're answer looks exactly what I'm aiming at, so I'm excited to get this sorted out in my code!)

Comment: 1) yeah, I include both methods just for the sake of showing both, and in my async I simulate what you're doing by using that `await Task.Delay(500);`

Comment: 2) Your GridView and DataTemplate should work just fine too with minor edits. I'm more comfortable with DataGrids and I hadn't seen your xaml when I was experimenting so that's what I defaulted to.

Comment: Cool I'm going to work thru this right now to see if I can integrate it into mine and get it all working!

Comment: yeah this looks great!